# most effective database synchronization scenario

Tags: database, firebase, sqlite, data-structures

I developed an app. I used 2 different databases in this application. The first of these databases (D1) is my database, where my most up-to-date data is kept and accessible to all applications. My second database (D2) is my database where I can continue to perform operations when the user (U) is not connected to the Internet.

[image]

I'm coming to my question. How should I check the lack of data between these two databases. Let me explain my method. I continue to pull and send data from D1, while at the same time writing my data to D2. Thus, D2 works with complete data in case of possible internet outage. I mark the actions I perform when there is no Internet connection with the help of a column in the database. When I connect to the Internet, I transmit marked data to the D1 database and make transactions accessible to other users.

Is the structure I want to build right? Is there a better way? Can you help me?

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: I use two different databases. The first is SQlite, the second is Firebase.

Comment: The approach sounds reasonable, but the devil is usually in the (many) details. I recommend starting your implementation, and posting back (probably with a new question) if you run into concrete problems.

Comment: thank you for your help.